# Jupyter Notebook is not showing the complete graph?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

any idea why is the following graph not showing completely? How can I fix this?

[image: Picture from Jupyter Notebook]

Code:

```
figsize = (15, 5)

feat_imp = pd.DataFrame({'Importance':rf.feature_importances_})    
feat_imp['feature'] = X.columns
feat_imp.sort_values(by='Importance', ascending=False, inplace=True)
feat_imp = feat_imp

feat_imp.sort_values(by='Importance', inplace=True)
feat_imp = feat_imp.set_index('feature', drop=True)
feat_imp.plot.barh(title=title, figsize=figsize)
plt.xlabel('Feature Importance Score')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to show your code along with your image

Comment: Ok, added the code

Comment: How about use `plt.tight_layout()` ?

Comment: No, that doesn't work